# perl @INC not complete when launching lighttpd

Tags: macos, perl, lighttpd

I am trying to run TrinotateWeb (v3.2.1) on my iMac (Catalina 10.15.6). It uses the light browser lighttpd (v1.4.55), which I installed with Homebrew.

When launching the server, it complains about not finding the HTML/Template.pm in @INC:

```
Can't locate HTML/Template.pm in @INC (you may need to install the HTML::Template module) 
(@INC contains: 
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Library/Perl/5.18 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/5.18 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 
.) at /Applications/Trinotate-v3.2.1/TrinotateWeb/cgi-bin/index.cgi line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/Applications/Trinotate-v3.2.1/TrinotateWeb/cgi-bin/index.cgi line 15.
```

However, HTML/Template.pm is well installed in the folder `/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5`. It was installed using `cpan HTML::Template`.

The problem seems to stem from @INC.

My .zshrc profile reference the above location with PERL5LIB:

```
PATH="/Users/simon/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5L$
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/simon/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB$
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/simon/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/simon/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

In the terminal, @INC contains PERL5LIB and hence links HTML/Template.pm:

```
➜  ~ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 4) configuration:
   
  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=19.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin osx397.sd.apple.com 19.0 darwin kernel version 18.0.0: tue jul 9 11:12:08 pdt 2019; root:xnu-4903.201.2.100.7~1release_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-ds -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dccflags=-g  -pipe  -Dldflags= -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseithreads -Duseshrplib -Dinc_version_list=none -Dcc=cc'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags =' -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector',
    optimize='-Os',
    cppflags='-g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-selector-opts)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/lib /usr/local/lib
    libs= 
    perllibs=
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.dylib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_HASH_FUNC_ONE_AT_A_TIME_HARD
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
                        PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV PERL_SAWAMPERSAND USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/<version> comes before system perl directories
    installprivlib and installarchlib points to the Updates directory
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jun  5 2020 17:34:07
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5"
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/simon/perl5"
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/Users/simon/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/simon/perl5"
  @INC:
    /Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4
    /Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
    .
```

What I don't get is why @INC when executing lighttpd does not list all paths as my actual environment shown above?

Comment: Is lighttpd being run by a different user than simon? Maybe it doesn't have permissions to read files under /Users/simon?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lighttpd, but I'm guessing it's run as a service that never touches your `.zshrc` file? One of few (but major) reasons for which I prefer installing an entire `perl` in my home dir (e.g. using `perlbrew`) over installed just modules (e.g. using local::lib)

Comment: The path you said the module is installed at is not included in `@INC`, as reported by the error message. Therefore perl cannot see it. Is there a reason you chose to install it there, and not in the regular perl library? I.e. one of the paths that are listed as included in `@INC`.

Comment: @DaveMitchell: lighttpd is run under ```/Users/simon``` (also, there is only one account on that computer), so I think this might not be a permission issue.
@TLP: The path is indeed not included, but I am wondering why is that because it is well listed in the ```@INC``` returned by ```perl -V```. There was not particular reason to put it there, just the location at which ```cpan``` automatically used (first time running ```cpan``` on this machine).
@ikegami: thanks for the suggestion. I will attempt installing another perl with brew on Monday.

Comment: @sihellem Sounds to me like a user mixup (perhaps webscripts are run with a different user), or you are using two different versions of perl. But it is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd exec's your CGI (or FastCGI) directly, so if your script is xxxxx.pl and contains `#!/usr/bin/perl`, that is what is executed.  (To be more explicit, zsh is not executed and .zshrc is not read, as others have said in the comments)

You can update the first line in those scripts to include `#!/usr/bin/perl -I...`, or you can modify lighttpd.conf to specify:

`setenv.add-environment = ("PERL5LIB" => "...")`

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv

You could also direct mod_cgi to execute a zsh shell script to execute perl, but doing so is slower and less efficient.

`cgi.assign = (".pl"  => "/home/simon/bin/zsh-bounce-perl")`

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv

and have the `zsh-bounce-perl` script contain something like

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
exec perl "$@"
```

Comment: I opted for the most elegant solution, i.e. setting ```setenv.add-environment = ("PERL5LIB" => "/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5")``` in ```lighttpd.conf```, with ```HTML/Template.pm``` located under ```/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5```.
However I still get the exact same error. Are there other parameters to modify?

Comment: If the Perl script has -T enabled (taint checking), then Perl will ignore PERL5LIB and other environment variables.  I suggest writing a simple Perl script which reflects the environment back to you, accessing the script through the web server, and reviewing the output.

Comment: I thought of this too, however the ```/Applications/Trinotate-v3.2.1/TrinotateWeb/cgi-bin/index.cgi``` is not executed in ```-T``` mode.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution (posted as a separate answer).  I am still curious if you used your test.pl to see if the Perl script saw $ENV{PERL5LIB} or not after you updated lighttpd.conf.

Comment: I just modified lighttpd.conf to test for that. The @INC signature is the same of the one posted in my answer, the correct PATH is displayed, but not under $ENV{PERL5LIB}

Answer (score 1):

I verified again which perl is used when the script `/Applications/Trinotate-v3.2.1/TrinotateWeb/cgi-bin/index.cgi` is executed: `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.

I therefore executed the following `test.pl` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print $_, "\n" for @INC;
```

Which returns well my full @INC where `HTML/Template.pm` is located:

```
➜  Desktop perl test.pl
/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/5.18.4
/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/simon/perl5/lib/perl5
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.18
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.18
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
.
```

As user mixup was suggested, I tried installing the package with root permission using `sudo cpan HTML::Template`. The package was installed at `/Library/Perl/5.18`.

With this workaround, lighttpd now works perfectly.